# Getting an ID and setting a function on mouse moving not working

Tags: javascript

Here I'm trying to set a function on mouse moving, but it doesn't work.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('giveUpDiv')
btn.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - btn.offsetLeft - btn.offsetParent.offsetLeft
    var y = e.pageY - btn.offsetTop - btn.offsetParent.offsetTop
    btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px')
    btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px')
}
```

Comment: what are `--x` and `--y` supposed to be? Those aren't valid CSS property names. (You also haven't explained what "not working" means.)

Comment: Can you make sure that you are calling the function that contains this piece of code at the page load or somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const btn = document.querySelector("#giveUpDiv");

btn.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
   var x = e.pageX - btn.offsetLeft - btn.offsetParent.offsetLeft
   var y = e.pageY - btn.offsetTop - btn.offsetParent.offsetTop

   btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + "px");
   btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + "px");
});
```